# Deface, how to add a class to a button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, overriding, spree

Good day.
I want to add parameters 'btn btn-primary' to a button in Spree app.
I also try to use Deface for this goal.
But the code below doesn't  work.

app/overirdes/add_class_btn.rb

```
Deface::Override.new(:virtual_path => %q{spree/products/_cart_form},
                     :name => %{add_class_thumbnails_to_products},
                     :set_attributes => %q{button#add-to-cart-button},
                     :disabled => false,
                     :attributes => {:class => 'btn btn-primary'})
```

Spree partial located there https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/app/views/spree/products/_cart_form.html.erb

And result should be on a picture below:
localhost:3000/products/product1

[image: btn button]
[image: div]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Deface::Override.new(:virtual_path => "spree/products/_cart_form",
:name => 'replace_add_to_cart_button',
:replace => "code[erb-loud]:contains('add-to-cart-button')",
:text => "<%= button_tag :class => 'large primary btn btn-primary', :id => 'add-to-cart-button', :type => :submit do %>",
:original => "<%= button_tag :class => 'large primary', :id => 'add-to-cart-button', :type => :submit do %>")
```

This will apply 'btn btn-primary' tag to the button.
I don't know why my first example doesn't want work.
But the goal is get.

Answer (score 3):

Usually when an override wasn't working for me it was because I was referencing the wrong version of Spree. For example, my project was using spree 1.0 but I was referencing 1.1 on github, so the `data-hook` names I was looking for or the file I was looking for didn't exist.

So now, instead of checking on github I look directly at the Spree gem my project is using. To do that use `bundle show spree`. You can goto that directory like so:

```
cd my_spree_project     # make sure you're in your spree project
cd `bundle show spree`
```

Another very helpful tool is `rake deface:get_result`.

> **deface:get_result** - Will list the original contents of a partial or
>   template, the overrides that have been defined for a that file, and
>   the resulting markup. get_result takes a single argument which is the
>   virtual path of the template / partial:

Run it to verify that your override is actually referencing something.

```
rake deface:get_result['spree/products/_cart_form']
```